# Coordinates from meters to degrees

Tags: neo4j, cypher, coordinates

I have a dataset with coordinates in meters. I need to convert them to degrees...
Example of coordinates : `{x: 652809.2865, y: 6863002.4359}`

I didn't find any way to convert this kind of coordinates into degrees.

Any one can help me please ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Meters and degrees are different units.

```
degrees(atan2(6863002.4359, 652809.2865)) = 84.56636948745165
```

The function names for the language you are using may vary.